# Search for a number and access info related in a text file, in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python. I have a large text file which has lots of numbers and looks like this. With 8 space gaps between the numbers.

```
100        200        300        400        500        ..
101        201        301        401        501        ..
102        202        302        402        502        ..
..         ..         ..         ..         ..         ..
```

I want to search for a number from the first column (eg 100 or 101 or 102), just say I want to search for 101 and then I want to use the numbers in front of it like 201, 301, 401 etc. at different places of my code. How to search for a particular number of my need and access the numbers in front of it individually as they will not be used together, they all will be used at different places individually? Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Related to astrophysics where I have to do some calculations, there are planetary candidates with names like "2714" and have parameters related to them. Consider this, 101 in this list is my planet and 201 ,301, 401 are parameters of this planet. I want that it open this text file search for planet in this file(I will input the planet name using the raw_input) and give me index or something (like as in a list). So that I can go to other columns of the same index and pick up parameters for calculations. I have [1:2,1] will give me "201". But how will I get the index of planet to fill there?

Comment: sorry I accidentally posted the first comment which didnt answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the text file and read it, and then store those numbers in a list, like this:

```
handle = open(name, 'r')
text = handle.read()
numbers = text.split()
```

To find a certain number, use a loop to run through the list and find the position of your desired number.
After that, if your text file follows a certain pattern,you can access other numbers in front of the first one, by adding fixed values to the index, in order to find the other positions in the list.

For example, if you have a text like this:

```
3   13

2   12
1   11
```

Its list when applying the above code would be this:

```
['3','13','2','12','1','11']
```

So you can have a clear idea on where the other desired values would be.

Comment: Sorry to say but the numbers dosen't have patterns , no patterns anywhere, this is just for illustration. The text file is large with around 15- 20 columns of parameters which look something like "527727.87092646223" and there are about hundreds of rows. I am new to working with text files. So changing them into list might not be the best way, I dont know just assuming.

Comment: Since you have a fixed number of columns and a fixed number of rows, with known data, you have a pattern. If the first column represents names, and the rest of the columns are parameters : you do always know where to find the 6th parameter of any name. It would be located in the list, at an index that equals : index of name + 6. And the logic applies for all the data.

Comment: The file has comments  so when I use this method it includes the comments too. The comments are of varying lengths, so I cant really count the no of words everywhere and I dont think it can work with different files. What I do to open them is                                                      file = "/home/sdha/......."  \n  x = np.genfromtxt(file) \n . Till now I was plotting graphs of complete columns vs columns so I used  x[ : ,0] for the first column and x[ : ,1] for complete 2nd column, this way the comments were no problem, they were ignored automatically. Thank you.

Comment: So is there any other way I can search. and pick up the parameters like above " x[1:2,1] for the second number of the 2 column ". the above method will work if there are no comments in files. The comments are like this  #Name, duration,.......... This data involves .......   A hashtag and comment in front of it. The comments are invisible to method I am using. Thank you.